# ionic how to show/hide content when logged out/in

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, authentication, firebase-authentication, ionic4

In my ionic app, sign up and log in works and the data is saved in Firebase but I don't how to hide or show a content in home page when user is logged in or out.

In my authentication.service.ts, uid (userID) is set when user is logged in

```
async signIn(email, password){
try{
  let userData = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword( email, password);
  this.uid = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
  return { success: true, uid: this.uid, email: email };
}
catch(error){
  return { success: false, error: error.message };
}
}
```

home.page.html

```
<ion-card-content>
sign up here
  <ion-button class="btnSignUp" fill="clear" color="medium" (click)="showSignup()">
      Sign up
  </ion-button>
</ion-card-content>
```

So I want to use that info in authentication.service.ts and only show that sign up button in my home.page.html when user is NOT logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `home.page.ts` do the following:

```
export class Home implements OnInit{
  currentUser : any;
  showBtn     : boolean = true;
  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.currentUser = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
    if(this.currentUser === null){
     this.showBtn = false;
      }
 }
```

Then in your html:

```
<ion-card-content *ngIf="showBtn">
sign up here
  <ion-button class="btnSignUp" fill="clear" color="medium" (click)="showSignup()">
  Sign up
 </ion-button>
</ion-card-content>
```

Here, you first retrieve the `currentUser`, if the user is not logged in then you can assign `showBtn` to `false` and then in the html use `ngIf` which will show/hide the button.

Comment: Thank you for the help. So basically, it should show button when user is not logged in, so I set this.showBtn = true; and It worked but after log in, it should disappear, but it did not. What is the reason?

Comment: Can u add console.log(this.currentUser); and yes if showbtn is false it shouldn't show the sign up button

Comment: I just checked it and realised the issue. So when I log in, it redirects to home page and it doesn't refresh the homepage and that is why the button status did not change to false. how to I redirect to home and refresh at the same time?

Comment: @H.Kim if you copied the code that i wrote exactly the same, it should be `ngIf="!showBtn">` in the html

Comment: no I didn't copy your code exactly. I changed it to `this.showBtn = true` and it works but it only works when go to other tabs and refresh home page. Also, for `console.log(this.currentUser);` it says null in other tabs/ pages. How do I fix it?

Comment: I actually figured it out